# How to inherit class name in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I get the class name of the child class instead of the parent class? Both print `a`, but it should print `b` in the second `var_dump()`.

```
 <?php
    class a
    {
        public $name;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->name=get_class();
        }
    }

    class b extends a
    {
        public function b()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
    }

    $a= new a();
    $b=new b();

    var_dump($a); //prints a
    var_dump($b); //prints a, i want to be printed b here
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `$this` to [`get_class()`](http://php.net/get_class):

```
$this->name = get_class($this);
```

Comment: it works! can you please explain why not without passing $this was not working? manual says that if it is in class context it dont need to pass anything in that parameter?

Comment: and also is it possible to do it with constant _ _CLASS_ _instead of get_class()? will it resolved to current child class properly?

Comment: @user1538127:  `get_class()`, when the argument is omitted, returns the name of the class where the function is called from.  Since it is instead of the `a` class,  it will return  "a" when the argument is omitted.   Using `__CLASS__` will **not** work.

Answer (score 1):

In a static method, `get_class()` and `__ CLASS __` will **not** work.

Only `get_called_class()` will work.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php